# Get Original URL instead of base64 url from src attribute

Tags: javascript, web-scraping

I am trying to get data from this site: https://balkangreenenergynews.com/country/romania/

Problem is that when I try to extract image url(image_link) via "src" attribute it return URL in base64 format.

I have give Output below:

```
[{link:
 'https://balkangreenenergynews.com/...nsson/',
image_link:
 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4...3ZnPg==',
lead_text:
 'Distribution ... farm.',
time: '29 July 2021',
author: '' }, ...]
```

Code:

```
const scraperObject = {
  url: 'https://balkangreenenergynews.com/country/romania/',
  async scraper(browser){
  let page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(this.url)
  .catch(error => console.error(error));
  try {
    await page.waitForSelector("div.four-boxes.multi-boxes", { visible: true });
    //console.info("Country News Page loaded");
    
    page.on("console", msg =>
      msg.type() === "error"
        ? console.error(msg.text())
        : console.info(msg.text())
    );
    let data = await page.evaluate(() => {
      const articles = document.querySelectorAll("div.bn-box");
      const textContent = elem => (elem ? elem.textContent.trim() : ""); // helper function
      const articleArray = [];
      //let element = await page.$('your selector')
      //await element.evaluate(el => el.textContent)
      articles.forEach(article => {
        
        //console.log(article.querySelector("div.bn-box-img > a img").getAttribute("src"))
        articleArray.push({
          title:
            textContent(article.querySelector("div.bn-box > a > h3")) || "",
          link: article.querySelector("div.bn-box > a")
            ? article.querySelector("div.bn-box > a").getAttribute("href")
            : "",
          image_link: article.querySelector("div.bn-box-img > a > img")
            ? article.querySelector("div.bn-box-img > a > img").getAttribute("src")
            : "",
          lead_text:
            textContent(article.querySelector("div.bn-box > p")).split(' ').slice(4).join(' ') ||
            "",
          time: textContent(article.querySelector("p > strong")) ||
          "",
          author: ""
            //textContent(article.querySelector(".entry-author a")) || ""
        });
      });
      //console.log(articles);
      //return;
      return articleArray;
    });
    console.log(data)

  } catch (error) {
    console.log(":(");
    //console.error("No articles found for " + country.slug + error);
  }
}}
```

How do I get that particular URL as I am saving these URLs directly to databases?

Comment: are you using puppeteer?

Comment: @JRichardsz, yes I am using puppeteer.

Answer (score 1):

### Puppeter is bothering us

I was able to replicate your code:

- https://github.com/jrichardsz/dokku-puppeteer-example/blob/rare-puppeter-behavior/app.js

According to the following research, it seams that **puppeter** is changing the real html.

I tried your code directly on browser console and I get this html of first article:

```
const articles = document.querySelectorAll("div.bn-box");
articles[0].innerHTML
```

[image]

But when I ran your puppeter code printing the first article (`console.log(articles[0].innerHTML);`), the **html for the same article changes**:

[image]

It seams that puppeter browser implementation is changing the html dom.

> I don't find any on internet about this puppeter behavior

### Just to check

If you click on some article, after its load, inspecting I see this:

[image]

I don't know but the origin page could be changing the response html according to the client:

- real browser for humans
- headless or in memory browser for automation (puppeter)

### Try with selenium instead puppeter

You could use [this](https://github.com/jrichardsz/selenium-nodejs-snippets/blob/main/hello-world/search_on_google_with_firefox.js) starter to use selenium instead puppeter

Comment: Is it possible to get all data from browser console as it is via puppeter? That way it would resolve issue. Actually I have lot of code based on pupetteer, so its kind of diff to shift on selenium. But if its only solution I will do it:(